# Does gcc/clang has option disallow their preprocessor to generate source file data

Tags: c++, c

I preprocessed this test.c to test.i by command `gcc -E -o test.i test.c`.
test.i has some source file data like `# 1 "test.h" 1` in test.i.
Could I have any idea let preprocessor not to generate those strings?

test.i

```
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 31 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "test.h" 1
int c;
# 1 "test.c" 2
```

test.c

```
#include "test.h"
```

test.h

```
int c;
```

Comment: On a totally unrelated note: Don't define variables in header files. Such variables will be defines in each [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) you include the header file in, and when you link them together you will have multiple definition errors.

Comment: @Kerndog Yes, this solved my problem. Thank your help.

Comment: To get back to your original question: I couldn't [find](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) a suitable option. On the other hand, those lines you are interested in to suppress all start with a hash sign (`#`). Wouldn't be difficult to write e. g. a python script to filter these out, just read the fine [line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3277512/1312382) and only print to target file if line doesn't start with a hash...